# How to remove one specific query parameter from URL in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

`http://localhost:3000/?search=test&type=abc&category=xyz`

After I search for test (among with type and category), the URL changes to the URL above.

```
return router.push(
      {
         pathname: `/`,
         query: {
             // something to do here...
         },
      },
      "",
      { scroll: false }
);
```

Next, I have an `onClick` with this `router.push`.

I would like to remove **ONLY** the search query and *keep the type and category queries*. How is it possible? The documentation doesn't mention anything about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `router.push` with the current query string, but omitting the `search` parameter.

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams(router.query);
params.delete('search');
const queryString = params.toString();
const path = `/${queryString ? `?${queryString}` : ''}`;

router.push(path, '', { scroll: false });
```

Given that you're currently at `/?search=test&type=abc&category=xyz`, the above will route you to `/?type=abc&category=xyz`. This will also handle scenarios where the `type` and `category` query parameters aren't present.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't completely clear in my question. This might work, but if I want to remove the search query in my app by clicking "clear", then the router.push runs (that you posted) and type + category will still show up as empty IF there is no type or category query in the url yet. Right?

Comment: Yes. I've updated my answer to handle cases where the other query params aren't in the URL yet.

Answer (score 8):

To remove the query param completely from the url:

```
const { paramToRemove, ...routerQuery } = router.query;
router.replace({
  query: { ...routerQuery },
});
```

Comment: This works like a charm, answer didn't work correctly for me, pay attention that paramToRemove is expected to be an object, you can grab it before like `const { nameOfQueryParam } = router.query;`

Answer (score 0):

let queries = Object.assign({}, router.query);

```
delete queries.search;
return router.push(
      {
         pathname: `/`,
         query: queries
      },
      "",
      { scroll: false }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove it by deleting the property in router.query

```
delete router.query.search;
router.push(router);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This won't remove the query parameter from url, but indeed remove it from router